# low memory problem during data import with Core Data on iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, core-data

I am running into some memory problems with my data import where I pull in some xml from a web service and save it in core data.

here is my code:

```
for (int m=0; m < [manufacturers count]; m++) {

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:kClientListURLv2, [[manufacturers objectAtIndex:m]ManufacturerID]]];
    NSLog(@"getting data:%@", url) ;
    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    int j = 0;
    for (NSDictionary* dict in array) {
        j=j+1;
        Client *entity = (Client*) [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Client" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
        //[entity setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:dict];
        [entity setBillingState:[dict valueForKey:@"BillingState"]];
        [entity setBillingCity:[dict valueForKey:@"BillingCity"]];
        [entity setBillingCountry:[dict valueForKey:@"BillingCountry"]];
        [entity setCurrentBalance:[dict valueForKey:@"CurrentBalance"]];
        [entity setArOver90:[dict valueForKey:@"ArOver90"]];
        [entity setPassword:[dict valueForKey:@"Password"]];
        [entity setPricingDiscount:[dict valueForKey:@"PricingDiscount"]];
        [entity setEmail:[dict valueForKey:@"Email"]];
        [entity setCompanyName:[dict valueForKey:@"CompanyName"]];
        [entity setClientID:[dict valueForKey:@"ClientID"]];
        [entity setAr6190:[dict valueForKey:@"Ar6190"]];
        [entity setBillingAddress2:[dict valueForKey:@"BillingAddress2"]];
        [entity setLastName:[dict valueForKey:@"LastName"]];
        [entity setContactName:[dict valueForKey:@"ContactName"]];
        [entity setAr3160:[dict valueForKey:@"Ar3160"]];
        [entity setSalesRepID:[dict valueForKey:@"SalesRepID"]];
        [entity setShippingAddress2:[dict valueForKey:@"ShippingAddress2"]];
        [entity setShippingCity:[dict valueForKey:@"ShippingCity"]];
        [entity setManufacturerID:[dict valueForKey:@"ManufacturerID"]];
        [entity setShippingState:[dict valueForKey:@"ShippingState"]];
        [entity setAr30:[dict valueForKey:@"Ar30"]];
        [entity setBillingZip:[dict valueForKey:@"BillingZip"]];
        [entity setShippingAddress:[dict valueForKey:@"ShippingAddress"]];
        [entity setShippingZip:[dict valueForKey:@"ShippingZip"]];
        [entity setURL:[dict valueForKey:@"URL"]];
        [entity setPhone:[dict valueForKey:@"Phone"]];
        [entity setCreditLimit:[dict valueForKey:@"CreditLimit"]];
        [entity setClientStatus:[dict valueForKey:@"ClientStatus"]];
        [entity setFax:[dict valueForKey:@"Fax"]];
        [entity setIsDeleted:[dict valueForKey:@"IsDeleted"]];
        [entity setShippingCountry:[dict valueForKey:@"ShippingCountry"]];
        [entity setClientNumber:[dict valueForKey:@"ClientNumber"]];
        [entity setBillingAddress:[dict valueForKey:@"BillingAddress"]];
        [entity setUsername:[dict valueForKey:@"Username"]];
        [entity setIsAddedToServer:[dict valueForKey:@"IsAddedToServer"]];
        [entity setFirstName:[dict valueForKey:@"FirstName"]];
        [entity setRepNumber:[dict valueForKey:@"RepNumber"]];
        [entity setManufacturer:[manufacturers objectAtIndex:m]];
        [entity setIsAddedToServer:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];

        for (NSDictionary* dict2 in [dict valueForKey:@"ShippingAddresses"]) {

            if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dict valueForKey:@"ShippingAddresses"]] length] > 1) {
                ShippingAddress *taggedItem = (ShippingAddress *) [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ShippingAddress" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
                [taggedItem setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:dict2];
                [taggedItem setClient: entity];

                NSError *error;
                if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
                    NSLog(@"Save Error: %@",error);
                }
            }   
        }

        if (j%saveThreshold==0) {
            NSLog(@"Saving after 500 items");
            NSError *error;
            if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
                NSLog(@"Save Error: %@",error);
            }
        }
    }

    [array release];
    NSError *entityerror;
    if (![managedObjectContext save:&entityerror]) {
        //  //Handle the error.
        NSLog(@"\n\n\n Error saving: %@ \n\n\n\n",entityerror);
    }
}
```

Basically this is looping through and creating all of my NSManagedObjects and then saving the context after every 500.

Code work great and is very fast but memory grows and if there are too may clients downloaded it crashes the app because of low memory.  Is there some sort of release or something I can do on the managedObjectContext - grabbing at straws here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try to put the hole code inside

```
for (int m=0; m < [manufacturers count]; m++) {
}
```

in a separate method and put some

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];
[pool drain];
```

around it. This should release any `NSArray *array` completely.
Don't ask me why it is not deleted on `release` but I had the same problem a few weeks ago.

You can run your project with Performance Tools and especially Object Allocation and Leaks.
It will show you, how much memory is used at which time.

Comment: this helped with other portions of this code but I am going to have to split my import in to different chunks, total data download size now is over 3O Megs. I think opening that is easting up alot of memory alone.

Comment: you should definitely split the download file. iPhone 3G has only around 40mb usable memory. You can also try to build a parser which decompose the objects while downloading new ones. (I think there is already a parser from url…) It would be much easier if you have multiple file and load each one separate, parse it with AutoreleasePool and then load the next one.